# Wrong format of SET

Tags: imacros

I want to run my script to check if the fuel value is above 150 to do `if`/`else` stuff.

When I try to run the script it returns with

> wrong format of SET command, line 8 (Error code: 910)"

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://cannonsatoshi.com/account
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=ID:fuel_value* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}

SET !VAR3 EVAL(" if {{!VAR2}}=>150{ 
   iimPlay("loop2.iim") 
} else {
   iimPlay("Wait.iim")
} ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t confuse Scripting Interface with the `EVAL` command (where only “pure” JavaScript is possible). If you want to use ‘if’-clause, try js-script like this:

```
iimPlayCode("TAB T=1" + "\n" + "URL GOTO=https://cannonsatoshi.com/account" + "\n" + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=ID:fuel_value* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n");

if (parseInt(iimGetExtract()) >= 150) 
   iimPlay("loop2.iim");
else
   iimPlay("Wait.iim");
```